# How do I configure angular to use base routes without trailing slashes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

## Desired behavior

I have a search page that lives at this URL:

`http://example.com/search`

The desired behavior is that the provided query parameters get passed to the page, and get updated as the user types a different query.

E.g.,

`http://example.com/search?q=foo`

results in the search box containing "foo" on page load. If the user types "delicious pancakes" into the search box, the location bar's URL will update automatically to this:

`http://example.com/search?q=delicious+pancakes`

This part is working fine; I'm using `$watch` to monitor the value of the query and then update the location bar via `$location.search('q', newValue)`.

But I'd like to use HTML5 mode (I am using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`), and I need the hashbang fallback to work for IE9 users.

I would like the hashbang fallback to look like this:

`http://example.com/search#?q=delicious+pancakes`

## The Problem

If I don't set the `<base>` element, the $location service treats everything after the domain as the path, so it actually falls back to this in IE9:

`http://example.com/#search?q=delicious+pancakes`

This results in the browser redirecting to the home page (i.e., it takes me away from the search page completely!)

So the best practice seems to be to use the `<base>` tag; so I set it to

`<base href="http://example.com/search/"></base>`

(Note the trailing slash; I understand this is required by both Angular and by the HTML spec.)

However, this means I must use the following URL:

`http://example.com/search/?q=delicious+pancakes`

(with the IE9 fallback being `http://example.com/search/#?q=delicious+pancakes`)

This works, but I don't want to require users to type that slash after "search" and before the question mark. Currently if I try to access the page via `http://example.com/search?q=foo`, I receive this error in the console:

```
TypeError: whole is undefined
```

This error is apparently caused because the $location service's `$$rewrite` function not returning anything. For reference, I'll copy the source from angular.js:

```
this.$$rewrite = function(url) {
    var appUrl, prevAppUrl;

    if ( (appUrl = beginsWith(appBase, url)) !== undefined ) {
      prevAppUrl = appUrl;
      if ( (appUrl = beginsWith(basePrefix, appUrl)) !== undefined ) {
        return appBaseNoFile + (beginsWith('/', appUrl) || appUrl);
      } else {
        return appBase + prevAppUrl;
      }
    } else if ( (appUrl = beginsWith(appBaseNoFile, url)) !== undefined ) {
      return appBaseNoFile + appUrl;
    } else if (appBaseNoFile == url + '/') {
      return appBaseNoFile;
}
```

**Is there any way I can achieve the desired behavior without the slash after "search", and still have IE9 support?**

Comment: Did you found a solution for your problem I want to get rid of the trailing slash

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional statement to exclude IE9 from HTML5mode:

```
if(!!$window.innerWidth && !$window.matchMedia)
  {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: false, requireBase: false});
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix("search");
  }
else
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});
```

**References**

- [AngularJS Error Reference / $location / nobase](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase#!)
- [AngularJS Documentation for $locationProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider#!)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question to "achieve the desired behavior without the slash after 'search'" also HTML5mode already has this fallback for browsers that don't have the history.pushState API (https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase#!)